# Creating a vector with 6 pointers(3 from base class and 3 from derived class)

Tags: c++

I have 2 simple classes, the base one has a `char*` and the derived one has the same `char*` and an `int`.

The task is to create a `vector` in `main.cpp` with 6 pointers, 3 from base class and 3 from derived class. Do you have any idea how do I do that?

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Mobilier {
protected:
    char* culoare;
public:
    Mobilier();
    Mobilier(char* cul);
    Mobilier(const Mobilier& m);
    ~Mobilier();
    void citire();
    void afisare();
};
```

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Mobilier.h"

class Canapea :public Mobilier {
protected:
    int nrpersoane;
public:
    Canapea();
    Canapea(char* cul, int nrpers);
    Canapea(const Canapea& c);
    ~Canapea();
    Canapea operator=(const Canapea& c);
    void citire();
    void afisare();
};
```

Comment: Sorry, this is too vague of a description. What you should do is: 1) make your best attempt to write your program 2) if you cannot figure out a ***specific*** problem with the resulting program: follow Stackoverflow.com's [help]'s instructions for creating a [mre], then [edit] your question and include it. See [ask] questions for more information. You must show your work, and ask a ***specific technical question*** when asking for help on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for something like this?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include "Mobilier.h"
#include "Canapea.h" 

std::vector<Mobilier*> vec(6);
vec[0] = new Mobilier(...);
vec[1] = new Mobilier(...);
vec[2] = new Mobilier(...);
vec[3] = new Canapea(...);
vec[4] = new Canapea(...);
vec[5] = new Canapea(...);
```